# How to extract noise when the noise on three data sets are near identical?

Tags: matlab, noise

I have a microphone array with three microphones placed in a small equilateral triangle. During recording, there is a lot of noise introduced by an ADC. However, I am not interested in reducing this noise before sampling - for learning, I want to remove this noise digitally as best as possible, given that the noise on each channel is near identical.

Given that their noise is near identical, I imagine it would be possible to correlate the signals in some way, even in the presence of a stronger signal with slight time delays. If possible, how can I remove this noise?

[image: From left to right: x1, x2 and x3. From upper to lower: Time series, spectral density and cross correlation r12, r23 and r31]

Comment: I would think this Q&A could give you some insight; in your case your signal of interest is likely the narrow band and the noise the wide band signal: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37902/adaptive-filtering-optimum-filter-length-and-delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the three measurements $y1$, $y2$ and $y3$ coming from three unknown signals $x1$, $x2$ and $x3$, which we could assume ***additive*** to some unknown common noise $x4$, we can write:
$$
y1=x1+x4\\
y2=x2+x4\\
y3=x3+x4
$$
or equivalently:
$$
y=Ax\\
A=[1,0,0,1;0,1,0,1;0,0,1,1]
$$
Again, assuming a enough ***noisy*** signal, we can have an standard [Recursive Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) algorithm for solving the standard LS projection recursively:
$$
\hat x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty
$$
This way, and if and only if the *additive* noise and the *noisy* signal suficciencies are met, you will solve for your three signals, *and* your coupled noise.

Because of the former, you even can express this solution using the [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)